# how to login in fba enabled SharePoint site when i use passwordFormat="Encrypted" in my web.config file

Tags: sharepoint, web-config, asp.net-membership, encryption, fba

using below code i am not able to login page. how i can validate user when i am using passwordFormat="Encrypted"

```
if (SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(ctxUri, txtUserName.Value.Trim(), encodedPassword))
           {
              string strDirectLink = "/Pages/Home.aspx";
              SPUtility.Redirect(strDirectLink.ToString(), SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);
           }
           else
           {
              lblErrMsg.Text = "Invalid username. Please try again";
           }
```

always code execute in else part and show "Invalid username. Please try again" message.

my CA+WP+STS web.config files

Answer (score 0):

SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser does work for authenticating a user.  You can check out it's use in the SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack, in MembershipRequest.cs.
https://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com

Make sure that you can login with that username and password from the SharePoint forms based login page first, to make sure that there's no issues with your membership web.config settings.

I generally don't recommend using 'encrypted' as a passwordFormat.  It can be difficult to get to work, as you have to make sure the same key is used on all SharePoint servers, or it won't be able to decrypt the passwords.

I suggest using a passwordFormat of Hashed.  It's more secure than encrypted, because it can't be decrypted to the original password.  It also doesn't require having the same key setup on all servers.